# Deleting the keys in an array of object and checking its length

Tags: javascript

```
var uniqueProperties = [];    
for (var i = 0, length = obj.length; i < length; i++) {
        for (var prop in obj[i]) {
            if (prop == null || prop == ' ') {
                delete obj[i][prop];
            }
        }
        for (var prop in obj[i]) {
            if (this.uniqueProperties.indexOf(prop) === -1) {
                this.uniqueProperties.push(prop);
            }
        }

    }
```

I want to first delete the keys with null or blank values, and then add them in the array and check its length.

I think its not getting deleted.

Comment: I think you're taking the right approach. However, in order to really help yourself out, use firefox with firebug, and inside of your for loops, output messages to yourself with the console like this:

console.log('Prop: '+prop);
or
console.log(uniqueProperties);.... stuff like that

Comment: Why don’t you use the uniqueness of property names of objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first loop, you're checking to see if "prop" is null or (incorrectly) the empty string, but that doesn't really make sense. You should be checking the **value** of that property of "obj[i]":

```
    if (obj[i][prop] == null || obj[i][prop] == '')
      delete obj[i][prop];
```

Also, your "uniqeProperties" list should also be "assisted" by a separate object so that you can avoid the poor algorithmic performance of repeated linear scans:

```
    var uniqueProperties = [], uniqueMap = {};

    // ...

    for (var prop in obj[i]) {
        if (!this.uniqueMap[prop]) {
            this.uniqueMap[prop] = true;
            uniqueProperties.push(prop);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is repeated linear scans and what does the uniqueMap object do in this case... why its declared as true.

Comment: It's a way of using the efficiency of the internal object property mapping code as a much faster way to determine whether a string is in a set of strings. Searching the array with "indexOf" is a "linear" search because the code has to check each element in the list, one after another, and you'd do that for each property. Using a map makes that a lot faster, especially if there are many such properties.

Comment: @Pointy: Could you give out a reason to my post, i just want to know why do you want to delete...

Comment: @Vinothbabu well *I* don't want to delete the properties, the original question asked about how to do it. I think it's a suspicious thing to do, but I don't think it's the worst thing ever. There are potentially good reasons to keep the map size under control.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to delete the keys....

```
for (var key in object) {

    if (!object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        continue;
    } //to skip inherited properties
    if (!key[object]) {
        continue;
    } //skip null or blank values
}
```

`delete obj[i][propertyName]` is a bad coding practice. You shouldn't delete properties directly in your incoming data since the results can sometimes be unpredictable and cause lots of headaches in the debugging stage.